# Data Analytics Documantaions

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, data-analysis, document-understanding

I am working as a data analyst in a company. Me and my colleagues use different tools and software to analyze the data and make the reports (e.g., Excel, Python, R, Alteryx, SQL, Tableau).
Each one use his/her favourite tools to do the tasks. Sometimes we use different tools in the same task.

We have a **problem** which is there is no good documantaions for the tasks. We have worked on many different analytics  tasks and the work have not well documented.  We sometimes have trouble in understanding the work  that other people have done. And understanding other works takes a long time.

I would like to find a good way for **documenting the tasks** or a **documentation template** to document the steps of analyzing the data, explain the logic, documenting data table.
Also, I would like to find a good solution to unify the sql scripts of extracting the data from DWH. I want to know how you documents your work?

Also, please provide me with good articles or best practices to documents data analytics tasks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to start a company wiki.

It is free and everyone could share and contribute with their own knowledge.

Some companies even share part of their knowledge with the public in order to make some branding.

Here are some wiki services for companies:

[https://document360.com/blog/internal-wiki/#:~:text=Traditional%20internal%20wiki-,What%20is%20an%20internal%20wiki%3F,effortlessly%20with%20other%20team%20members](https://document360.com/blog/internal-wiki/#:%7E:text=Traditional%20internal%20wiki-,What%20is%20an%20internal%20wiki%3F,effortlessly%20with%20other%20team%20members).

Here are some tips:

https://kipwise.com/blog/wiki-best-practices

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906917/what-are-some-examples-of-how-your-company-uses-a-wiki-for-development

Stack overflow could also be a good option:

https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams-free?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=kb_teams_search_brand_emea-dach&_bt=509747536246&_bk=stack%20overflow%20free&_bm=b&_bn=g&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1sucBhDgARIsAFoytUsignA5u3eu_PgM4R0j6Ry5-WXBm4j8nGmgvqgRYgBxwrhZ6QHr7N0aAquMEALw_wcB

A last tip: sharing knowledge with wiki is important, but if there is a service like google colab or streamlit that could execute code interactively (in addition to sharing knowledge), it could be even better.

https://streamlit.io/

For example:

https://share.streamlit.io/harmkenn/python-stat-tools/main/app.py

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information.